# IndexPath.row on a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an app in which you can have some details of something and then inside that thing you have a sub-category of things. I have made a button as there was not enough room for a navigation item and I can't seem to be able to call only the items that are assigned to that in my nsmutablearray. I have tried to used `initWithIndexPath:indexPath.row` though it comes up with this error:

> Use of undeclared identifyer "indexPath"; did you mean "NSIndexPath"

This is the code for my tableView inside my tableView:

```
#import "PRViewController.h"

#import "Patient.h"

#import "LSAppDelegate.h"

#import "LSViewController.h"

#import "LSAppDelegate.h"

#import "Patient.h"

#import "PatientController.h"

#import "AddPatientController.h"

#import "treatmentController.h"

@interface PRViewController ()

@end

@implementation PRViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.title = @"Treatments";
    LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    patients = delegate.patients;
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)add:(id) sender{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    if(self.tableView) {
        NSMutableArray *indices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i < patients.count; i++) {
            [indices addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        }
        NSArray *lastIndex = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:patients.count inSection:0]];
        if (self.tableView) {
            for (int i=0; i < patients.count; i++) {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[indices objectAtIndex:i]];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    treatmentController *AddPatient = [[treatmentController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AddPatient animated:YES];
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL) animated {
    if ( editing != self.editing ) {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    }
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if ( nil == cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d, patients.count = %d", indexPath.row, patients.count);
    Patient *thisPatient = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (thisPatient.treatmentName.length > 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = thisPatient.treatmentName;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {

    }
    if (self.editing) {
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [patients count];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {
        [patients removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    PatientController *patient = [[PatientController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    [delegate.navController pushViewController:patient animated:YES];
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Please say if you want any more code or information and please answer as soon as you can

file for the button I am pushing with:

```
#import "PatientController.h"

#import "LSAppDelegate.h"

#import "Patient.h"

#import "PRViewController.h"

@interface PatientController ()

@end

@implementation PatientController



- (id)initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( ( self = [super init]) ) {
        index = indexPath;
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)PatientRecords:(id)sender {
    PRViewController *AddPatient = [[PRViewController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AddPatient animated:YES];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Patient *thisPatient = [delegate.patients objectAtIndex:index.row];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.title = thisPatient.patientName;
    patientNameView.text = thisPatient.patientName;
    patientFirstNameView.text = @"Firstname:";
    patientSurnameView.text = thisPatient.patientSurname;
    patientSurnameNameView.text = @"Surname:";
    patientDoBView.text = thisPatient.patientDoB;
    patientDoBDateView.text = @"Date of Birth:";
    patientHomeView.text = thisPatient.patientHomeNumber;
    patientHomeNumberView.text = @"Home No:";
    patientMobileView.text = thisPatient.patientMobileNumber;
    patientMobileNumberView.text = @"Mobile No:";
    patientAddressView.text = thisPatient.patientAddress;
    patientAddressView.editable = NO;
    patientAddressPlaceNumberView.text = @"Address:";
    patientEmailView.text = thisPatient.patientEmail;
    patientEmailAddressView.text = @"Email:";

    patientPictureView.image = thisPatient.patientPicture;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL) animated {
    if ( editing != self.editing ) {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        patientAddressView.editable = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where ur app is getting crashed.

Comment: PLease clarify your `UIElements`. This `some details of something and then inside that thing ` is VERY VAGUE.

Comment: I pit up the code for the extra tableView

Comment: I have to go out will be back at about 4:10

Comment: you do not have a variable indexPath yet. Moreover you try to use `indexPath.row`, which is an integer, as a parameter of the type `NSIndexPath`. This won't work anyway.

Comment: @Herm so what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)PatientRecords:(id)sender {
    PRViewController *AddPatient = [[PRViewController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AddPatient animated:YES];
}
```

This code looks to be the culprit, you're not declaring the variable `indexPath` anywhere, you need to use `index` rather than `indexpath` from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use of undeclared identifyer "indexPath"; did you mean "NSIndexPath"
```

This error only happen if your do not declare indexPath but try to use it. As Xcode compiler's code sense detect and show you hint that it may be NSIndexPath instead of indexPath. check the use and declaration of indexPath.